# Linux Ubuntu only dummy output audio device. I've ran hardware probe and have ID but not sure how to install drivers/kernels etc

Tags: drivers, sound, kernel, hardware

My sound output device is showing only dummy output. I've ran a hardware probe and got my hardware device information (screenshot attached) but  I'm very new to linux so I'm not sure about how installing drivers works or what even is a kernel. I've installed ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and I believe my kernel version 5.19.0 which should be compatible according to linux-hardware.org but I'm literally stumped.

Would really appreciate some help! Thanks!

[Hardware Probe Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB23W.png)

EDIT:

I believe there was some issue with fast boot. When restarting my laptop if I don't let the computer rest for a few seconds before rebooting it back up again then the audio devices are not recognized.

Comment: uname -r gives 
5.19.0 -32-generic

and settings -> about shows OS Name: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. Maybe something about when I built the installation files with rufus it mentioned downloading some update for the version? but those details seems corrent

Comment: My mistake, I've corrected the question. However it does state that it's a LTS version?

Comment: I thought it shouldn't be too difficult for someone who knows what they're doing but I'm just an absolute noob at linux :/